# How to move focus to custom inputView

Tags: swift

## Given:

`UITextField` with a `UIPickerView` as `inputView`.
Works like a charm, you tap in the field, keyboard with the picker view appears.

## Problem:

External keyboard navigation.
When an external keyboard is connected a user has to move the focus to the pickerView via `ctrl-tab` through all views on the screen until the pickerView is reached. This gets tedious very fast if there are multiple form fields or a lot of other interactive elements on the screen.

## Wanted:

A way to automatically shift the focus over to the keyboard/pickerView - to be able to immediately start selecting values.

I can't seem to find any solutions despite two days of research. Any advise appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` when you set data it will redirect focus to `yourTextField`

For example:

`func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) { ... setting data yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder() }`

Comment: Thank you. The problem isn't the textfield (it keeps the focus the entire time while navigating with ctrl-tab), it's that the focus should go to the pickerView instead of having to ctrl-tab 20 times each time.

Comment: try `yourPickerView.becomeFirstResponder()` it it will redirect focus to `yourPickerView`

Comment: Thank you, I tried that already. Problem is the `pickerView` is used as an inputView / keyboard. In this case it doesn't react to `becomeFirstResponder`. I need something that sets the focus on the keyboard, which then will allow changes to `pickerView`